# Hold on does not work properly

Tags: matlab

I have written the following matlab code to test least square regression:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
y = [1 4 9 16 25 36];

hold on
scatter(x, y );
hold on
%Linear_regrassion
    n = length(x);
    a = (n*sum(x.*y) - sum(x)*sum(y)) / n*sum(x.^2) - (sum(x))^2
    b = mean(y) - a * mean(x)
%end
x = 1:8;
plot(x, a*x + b);
```

The `scatter` function works fine when I comment out `plot(x, a*x + b);`. and it looks like this: 
[image]

But when I add `plot(x, a*x + b);` to plot my estimated line, The output looks like this: 
[image]

My guess is that Im not using `hold on` right. What can i do to fix this issue?

Comment: Check your regression coefficients: `a` is `1.0706e+04`, `b` is `-3.7458e+04` - this cannot be right for the blue circle marker data you show, and must instead be an error in your regression code rather than in plotting.

Comment: look at your y-axis. that is your issue.

Comment: But indeed they do. You are using the `x` and `y` values to compute the regression coefficients `a` and `b`, which you then use to plot the red line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculation of `a` is wrong: you need parentheses in the denominator of the computation of `a`. However, `hold on` works well.

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
y = [1 4 9 16 25 36];

scatter(x, y,'*');
hold on
%Linear_regrassion
    n = length(x);
    a = (n*sum(x.*y) - sum(x)*sum(y)) / (n*sum(x.^2) - (sum(x))^2)
    b = mean(y) - a * mean(x)
%end
x = 1:8;
plot(x, a*x + b);
```

Comment: What is the difference between this code and the original code ?

Comment: For one, it produces an error. The answer also lacks any details on why it's supposed to work.

Comment: You should use "hold on" only after issuing a plot command, or a command with an embedded plot, like `scatter()`.   But the real "issue" is simply the appearance of the plot, because your second plot has a much wider span of y-values than the first.

Comment: I added some explanations in the answer. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Your code was still erroring out due to replacing `.*` and `.^` with `*` and `^`.  I took the liberty of editing your code to fix it.